# Redmine Eclipse-Mylyn Plugin cannot modify tasks

Tags: eclipse, redmine, mylyn

I've installed mylyn connectors for redmine and eclipse. After I executed `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails` and updated my `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` setting in config/environment.rb the plugin worked and i can connect to the repository.

I can also read tasks from the repo but I'm not able to modify them from eclipse ide. if i want to submit i cant authenticate... did I miss something? it seems, that i'm somehow stuck in a read-only mode?

I'm currently using on client side:
Eclipse/Mylyn 3.6.2
Mylyn Connector: Redmine 0.3.4.201109150625
and on server side:
Redmine 1.2.1.stable (MySQL)

Comment: I have no experience with Redmine, but have used Mylyn a lot with different connectors (JIRA and Trac mostly). You should add at least the versions of the software you are using: redmine, eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I also checked API Key in the eclipse taskrepository setup.